# find muli lines in file from other file

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have text file that have multi lines I want to search for lines containing some text and add # at the start of those lines.

ex:
file1 that I want to change it

```
acnet           6801/tcp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
acnet           6801/udp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
dlip            7201/tcp                # DLIP
dlip            7201/udp                # DLIP
ssp-client      7801/tcp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
ssp-client      7801/udp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
```

I want to find ports located in inputfile1. input file one contains:

```
6801
7801
```

so the final output of file1 will be like this:

```
#acnet           6801/tcp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
#acnet           6801/udp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
dlip            7201/tcp                # DLIP
dlip            7201/udp                # DLIP
#ssp-client      7801/tcp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
#ssp-client      7801/udp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
```

I tried

```
cat /etc/services |grep -f ports.txt | awk  '{ print"#" $g}';
```

but this give me the output to screen.
How to change them in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk -F"[ \t]*|/" 'NR==FNR{A[$1]; next} $2 in A { printf "#" }1' ports.txt /etc/services > newfile
```

If the output is correct, you can copy it to `/etc/services`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/6801\|7801/ {s/^/#/}' input
#acnet           6801/tcp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
#acnet           6801/udp                # ACNET Control System Protocol
dlip            7201/tcp                # DLIP
dlip            7201/udp                # DLIP
#ssp-client      7801/tcp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
#ssp-client      7801/udp                # Secure Server Protocol - client
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ..its not only just these two ports there maybe 20 i just give an example

Comment: you could wrap the whole sed script in a loop which reads the port one at a time and does the commenting for that port - but it would do one port at a time. alternatively, add all the ports in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP=$(cat ports.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /|/g')
sed -E -i -e "/[[:space:]]$REGEXP\// s/^/#/" inputfile1
```

This constructs an extended regular expression from the contents of `ports.txt`, and then uses them to select particular addresses (lines) in `inputfile1` to have a `#` character pre-pended.

The regex is "anchored" with a space at the beginning and a `/` at the end so that you don't match more than you specify - e.g. without the anchors, a `25` in `ports.txt` would not only match port 25, it would match ANY port containing the number `25` somewhere in it, including `2501`, `1025`, `250`, and many more.

BTW, if you want to be able to have comments in the ports.txt, use this:

```
REGEXP=$(sed -e 's/#.*//' ports.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /|/g')
sed -E -i -e "/[[:space:]]$REGEXP\// s/^/#/" inputfile1
```

The first version above will **ONLY** work correctly if `ports.txt` contains nothing but port numbers, spaces and empty lines - any extraneous characters (especially those that have special meaning in regexps) will cause unpredictable and almost-certainly undesirable results.

The second version deletes comments (i.e. everything after, and including, any `#` character on a line) so also allows (ignores) any character in a comment.

It will also fail if the ports listed in ports.txt causes the `sed` command to exceed the maximum command line length.  As this is typically around 128KB, this is very unlikely to be a problem in this case, but it's worth noting in case you use this technique for other tasks.